# Is there any way to loop Scrapy over different formdata?

Tags: python, scrapy, jupyter-notebook

I work for a logistics company and part of what we're trying to automate is staying on top of tracking statuses for various shipments.

I have developed a web scraper that works beautifully for taking an excel sheet that contains tracking numbers, and using those numbers to scrape tracking statuses from a carrier's website AS LONG AS THE LIST OF NUMBERS IS LESS THAN 10. This is because the carrier's website only allows for 10 tracking numbers at a time.

However, in our plan to automate our entire tracking division, we will need to deal with lists much longer than 10 numbers.

The primary problem I'm running into is that Scrapy requires me to restart the kernel in Jupyter notebook each time I want to run it, and this prevents me from chunking the list of tracking numbers into individual lists of ten.

Is there a way to loop Scrapy from within?

Up to this point I've managed to chunk the list of tracking numbers into lists of ten, and I've managed to run Scrapy with individual lists of ten or less tracking numbers and it works beautifully.

```
import scrapy
import pandas as pd
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


file = r"C:\Users\amars\Desktop\ODFL Tracking 4_23_2019.xlsx"

xl = pd.ExcelFile(file)

df1 = xl.parse('Data',names=['Ruan ID#','Carrier Pro','Tracking Status'])

prolist = df1['Carrier Pro'].tolist()
prolist = [' ' + str(i) for i in prolist]


def chunk(seq):
    a,b = divmod(len(seq),10)
    listy = []
    i = 0
    last = 0

    while i<a: 
        listy.append(seq[last:(last+10)])
        i = i+1
        last = last + 10

    listy.append(seq[last:(last+b)])

    return listy

if len(prolist) > 10:

    scraped_data = []
    prolist = chunk(prolist)


    class ODFL(scrapy.Spider):
        name = "ODFL"

        for k in prolist:     
            prolist1 = k
            prolist1 = ''.join(prolist1)

                        #start requests method
            def start_requests(self):
                url1 = "https://www.odfl.com/Trace/standard.faces"
                yield scrapy.Request( url = url1 , callback=self.parse )


            def parse(self, response):
                        request = scrapy.FormRequest.from_response( response,
                        formxpath='//*[@id="traceForm:j_idt26"]/fieldset/textarea',                                      
                        formdata={'traceForm:j_idt31': prolist1},
                        callback=self.parse2
                        )

                        yield request

            def parse2(self, response):
                for i in [2,3,5,6,8,9,11,12,14,15]:
                    text1 = response.xpath('/html/body/div[7]/div/form/span[1]/div/div['+str(i)+']/fieldset/div[3]/div[2]/text()').extract_first()
                    scraped_data.append(text1)





process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(ODFL)
process.start()


print(scraped_data)
```

I expect the output of scraped_data to be a list of thirteen statuses, but instead I get [].

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `def closed(self, reason):` hook.

In there you can restart:

```
process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(ODFL)
process.start()
```